# Mule standalone Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd'

Tags: java, xsd, mule, mule-studio

I am trying to deploy a mule app on mule standalone 3.7.0, but when running I occur this error:

org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is not .

App was developed in Anypoint Studio with mule server 3.7.3. Where is no transform-message element in 3.7.0? How to add this xsd into mule standalone?

Comment: Which version you are using? community or enterprise?

Comment: Ye.. i found what this element available only in EE version.. So where is question: what is the best way to make web-service output message with payload data according web-service xsd schema?

Comment: You can use xslt for example, but that depdends on the source and target formats.

Comment: Source is data from database (list payload). Target is web service output (xml according xsd schema).

Comment: Did you found out how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was about Mule Enterprise Edition. Transform message not available in CE. So im using custom java transformer.

Comment: I am also facing same issue do u know how to use custom java transformer.